# Powershell v3 Instantiate classes

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've tried two ways to instantiate a class in Powershell v3:

```
$regex = New-Object -Type System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex -ArgumentList '\/\/.*' | Get-Member
$regex::Replace("//hey", "")
```

And:

```
$netregex = [regex]::new('\/\/.*') | Get-Member
$nosingleline = $netregex::Replace("//hey", '')
```

The first way yields this:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Type'.
>
> At line:2 char:1
>
> - $regex::Replace("//hey", "")
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidCastException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException

The second way yields this:

> Method invocation failed because
>   [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex] doesn't contain a method named
>   'new'. At line:4 char:1
>
> - $netregex = [regex]::new('//.*') | Get-Member
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Answer (score 3):

Remove `| Get-Member` from both commands. It is changing the ultimate object type being output on those lines.

Also use `.` to access the method:

```
$netregex = [regex]::new('\/\/.*')
$nosingleline = $netregex.Replace("//hey", '')

$regex = New-Object -Type System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex -ArgumentList '\/\/.*'
$regex.Replace("//hey", "")
```

Comment: The first gives me this error: `Method invocation failed because [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex] doesn't contain a method named 'new'.` The second one works.

Comment: It might be a PowerShell version issue. Both work under PS5.1

Comment: Yeah that's why I specifically said Powershell v3 in the title, I got no choice at the moment